# Dynamic Scrapy settings

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I have a single Scrapy project with multiple spiders. This project is hosted on a scrapyd instance.
I would like to be able to dynamically change settings in the projects settings.py file (such as DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES).

Is it possible to change these settings at the time of sending a request to the scrapyd instance. Note that I don't want to create multiple projects as this will result in duplicating common code across projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters to scrapyd and change settings using the -d argument

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider -d setting=DOWNLOAD_DELAY=2 -d arg1=val1
```

Comment: How about starting scrapy with a different settings file, like Django allow us?

Comment: Thanks, but how would I set a dictionary style setting?  

I've tried the following  
  
`curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=GenericCrawl -d spider=Generic -d "setting=ITEM_PIPELINES={'GenericCrawl.pipelines.DefaultValuesPipeline': 299,'GenericCrawl.pipelines.MySQL':300}" 
`  
  
but I get the following error  
  
`[Launcher,4746/stderr] dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Comment: I haven't tried but what I would probably do is set a variable that's checked in each middleware and then pass that to scrapyd. Not as elegant but it'll work.

Comment: I've finally got a chance to come back to this. In the end it looks like passing in a "profile" variable and then setting the dictionary settings was the only way to go. Thanks